# How to calculate moment of inertia of a circular disc?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

[image]

**My Attempt:** This lamina is a circular disk centred at the coordinates $(a,0). $ We have to find the moment of inertia about the line $x=a.$ Consider a vertical strip of width $dx$ and of length $2\sqrt{ax-x^2}$ on both sides of the vertical axis. Then the mass of this strip will be $2\rho x\sqrt{ax-x^2}=2x\sqrt{ax-x^2}.$ The distance of the strips from the axis of rotation is $a-x$ and $2a-x$. Thus we get the following two integrals,
$$I_{x=a}=2\int_{0}^{a}(a-x)^2\sqrt{ax-x^2}+2\int_{a}^{2a}(2a-x)^2 \sqrt{ax-x^2}.$$ I can evalaute these integrals, but I just wanted to know whether this is the right approach or not. Thanks you.

Comment: The point is what means "vertical" in this context. I think it doesn't mean "around the $(a,y)$ axis" but "around the $z$ axis". I am not completely sure, but the hint is of no help at all with the first meaning and make things very easy with the second. Anyway, with the hypothesis of the first meaning, your calculations seem ok.

Comment: @RafaBudría the answer I am getting by this approach is $\frac{\pi a^4}{4}$, whereas the answer at the end is $\frac{\pi a^4}{64}.$

Comment: $\frac{\pi a^4}{4}$ is the solution for the disc rotating around the line $x=a$, but with the disk rotating around the line $z=0$ must be $\frac{\pi a^4}{2}$